# Laravel Error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: excel, laravel

I want to import excel, and my code of controller is:

```
 $path = $request->file('file')->getRealPath();
          $dataOfMember = Excel::toArray(new InterfaceMember(), $path);
          
          $dataOfMember = $dataOfMember[0];
          $insert_dataOfMember = [];

        foreach ($dataOfMember as $row) {
            $result = DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')");
        
            $insert_dataOfMember[] = [
                'kodeToko' => $kodeToko = session('authData')['kodeToko'],
                'idMember' => $result[0], 
                'RefereceID' => $row[0],
                'KodeMember' => $row[1],
                'NamaMember' => $row[2], 
                'JenisIdentitas' => $row[3], 
                'NomorIdentitas' => $row[4], 
                'AlamatMember' => $row[5], 
                'KodePos' => $row[6], 
                'JenisKelamin' => $row[7], 
                'TglLahir' => $row[8], 
                'NoHp' => $row[9],
                'PointReedem' => $row[10],
                'RpMember' => $row[11],
            ];
        }
      
          if (!empty($insert_dataOfMember)) {
              DB::table('uplMemberDeposite')->insert($insert_dataOfMember);
          }
      
        
        return redirect()->back();
```

when i do dd`( DB::select(" select dbo.fcIdMember(".$this->kodeToko.", '".$row[1]."')") );` this is the result

```
     array:1 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\ToolsInterfaceDataController.php:105
  0 => {#319 ▼
    +"": "202304110002"
  }
]
```

if i write `'idMember' => $result[0]->columnName,` how i write my colmn name when the name column is empty? how to slove this case? how to call function from my DB?

anyone please help me?

Comment: You would wrap it inside `empty` if I correctly understood your question you just needed to check whether the columnName exists and not null?

Comment: So ... whe  you get an error, you look in your laravel.log and copy/paste the entire stacktrace of that error in your original question.